# how do i check if two values are true in separate dataframes using a unique identifier? PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have

df1:

| id | snack |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | chips |
| 123 | pretzels |
| 789 | chips |
| 246 | pretzels |

df2:

| id | treat |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | cake |
| 789 | brownie |
| 246 | brownie |
| 456 | brownie |

how can i check if an "id"["snack"] == "chips" AND if an id["treat"]== "brownie" and keep the number of matches in a variable?
i have the below but it doesn't work - says that it is ambiguous.

```
matched=0
for row in range(len(df1)):
    idd = df1.iloc[row]['id']
    if idd in df2['id'].values:
        if (df1.iloc[row]['snack']=='chips') and (df2[df2['id'] == idd]['treat'] == 'brownie'):
            matched+= 1
        if (df1.iloc[row]['snack']=='pretzels') and (df2[df2['id'] == idd]['treat'] == 'cake'):
            matched+= 1
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: For Pandas `&` has to be used to combine conditions and not `and`

Answer (score 0):

Lets not complicate things using loops

```
# Map treat to snacks using predefined dictionary
df2['snack'] = df2['treat'].map({'brownie': 'chips', 'cake': 'pretzels'})

# Inner merge on id and snack
result = df1.merge(df2)
```

Result

```
result

    id     snack    treat
0  456     chips  brownie
1  123  pretzels     cake
2  789     chips  brownie

len(result)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

[Merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) two dataframes on `id` and count for *truthy* conditions:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
matched = (((merged.snack == 'chips') & (merged.treat == 'brownie'))
           | ((merged.snack == 'pretzels') & (merged.treat == 'cake'))).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two dataframes on the `id` column, query the result for rows matching your condition, and assign the resulting number of rows to a variable:

```py
n_matches = df1.merge(df2, on='id'
                     ).query("snack == 'chips' and treat == 'brownie'"
                            ).shape[0]
```